# Magento 2. Product not visible in any category or product listing

Tags: magento2, products

None of my products are visible in any product listing,category view,search.

I've checked all the usual suspects.

- Products are enabled, stock is not managed, they are assigned to website etc.
- Indexers have run successfully. checked the tables myself.
- Ran setup:upgrade, static:content, code generation
- Permissions on media, generated, var,pub, app,etc are 777. Ownership is magento:www-data.
- Crons ran successfully.
- Nothing in magento logs.
- Nothing in apache logs.
- Nothing in browser console.
- htaccess files are present.

I can see the products by individual url, only product listings are affected.

It is worth to note that I have a custom admin url. And all requests to backend are handled by a server and all requests to frontend are handled by another server.

I'm using Redis for cache and memcached for session storage.

With the same code I can't reproduce this on my local machine.

I had a similar issue at a previous deploy and fixed it with full permissions on media folder.

I suspect this is caused either by the separation of the nodes (admin -> one server, web -> another server) either by some server configuration.

Any hints, pointers to debugging this?

Comment: Are you using varnish (if you are using **sudo service varnish restart**)? Check the configuration are the same of Default Store View.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: check if your products setting is not changed on store view level basis. because sometime it happens no matter whatever settings you change it doesn't work. so check if products settings are not configured on store level rather then website level.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using varnish cache:

```
varnishd -V
```

If you are using do a restart:

```
sudo service varnish restart
```

If not:

- Clear redis cache.
- Check the Product are enabled in store view.
- Check for CDN.
- Check if you have Opcache , do a php-fpm restart.

Comment: No  Varnish on the machine.
Single Store Mode on.
Restarted the services multiple times.